Repeat a list of letters (macOS14.5)
I want to repeat a keyboard sequence every second. For example I would like to press A, wait a second on R wait a second then B and start the loop again indefinitely. I  want to perform multiple key presses with an interval of one second when the Chrome browser is open. I started to make an example, but it doesn't work.

this code work But how to run it in a loop?

tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Google Chrome"
      set frontmost to true
      key code 0
      delay 0.1
      key code 15
      delay 0.1
      key code 11
      delay 0.1
      key code 53
  end tell
end tell



Try it as a Applescript, not Javascript.
